# Get last div with the same data- attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I select the last div from div groups with the same data-id?
I tried to use .last and get last div with :contains but didn't worked.

HTML:

```
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".rentals_reservation").each(function(i, value) {
        var id = $(value).attr("data-id").;
        console.log(id);
    })
```

Comment: Do you know which specific data-id you want? or do you need to pick each last div for all data-id s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the question, but sounds like you want to select all of the last divs from the ones that have the same data-id.  ie the 2 that you have marked with a "*".

You can:

- get a unique list of IDs
- loop through to return the elements

snippet below does this and hides the elements (to show it's selected them).

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121880/2181514
var ids = $(".rentals_reservation").map(function() { return $(this).data("id"); }).toArray();
var uniqueids =  [...new Set(ids)]
var lastdivs = $(uniqueids).map(function() { return $("[data-id=" + this + "]").last()[0] });
$(lastdivs).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407*</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227*</div>
```

Comment: Well, this one worked like a charm + easy to understand. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Well you can make a selector and select the elements and select the last one

```
console.log($('[data-id="' + id + '"]').last())
```

Comment: Shortest and simpliest.

Answer (score 2):

Just form an object. The data-id is a key and element itself as a value. After loop each item in the object points to the latest element with "such" `data-id` attribute:

```
var dataIdsMap = {};
$(".rentals_reservation").each(function(i, value) {
        var id = $(value).attr("data-id").;
        dataIdsMap[id] = $(value);

    })
 console.log(dataIdsMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

This logic gets all the ids, reduces them to the unique ones, and finally finds the last element for each id.

```js
var $allReservations = $('.rentals_reservation');

console.log(
$allReservations.map(function getTheIds(){
  return this.getAttribute('data-id');
}).get().reduce(function getTheUniqueIds(collection, element){
  if (collection.indexOf(element) < 0) collection.push(element);
  return collection;
}, []).map(function findTheLastElementForEachId(element){
  return $allReservations.filter('[data-id="'+ element +'"]').last();
})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your selection I think an `array` can help, please check the following demo, in which I start to store a unique value of each `id` in an array and then select the last `div` with the same `id`:

```js
var existingIds=[];
var selectedElements=[];
$(".rentals_reservation").each(function(i, value) {
        
         if( !existingIds.includes($(value).data("id")) )
         {
           existingIds.push($(value).data("id"));
          
           selectedElements.push($(".rentals_reservation[data-id='"+$(value).data("id")+"']:last"));
         }         
    })
    console.log(existingIds);
    $.each(selectedElements,function(index, element){
     console.log($(element).text());
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">1.Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">2.Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">3.Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">1.Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">2.Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">3.Booking id: 3227</div>
```

Comment: Close, but you never store the element.

Comment: The array only holds the data id, of which there are duplicates. Examining the array after this pass will not yield the last div of id=3407, nor the last div of id=3227 but instead only 3407,3227.

Answer (score 0):

Try It. It may help you;

```js
var last = $(".rentals_reservation").last().data("id");
var values = [];
$(".rentals_reservation").each(function(i, v){
  if($(this).data("id") === last){
    values.push($(this).data("id"));
  }
})

console.log(values);
```

```css
#result{
  color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3407">Booking id: 3407</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Booking id: 3227</div>
*<div class="rentals_reservation" data-id="3227">Last One Booking id: 3227</div>

<br /><br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: If you're just selecting the last one, it would be `$(".rentals_reservation").last()` - no need to loop through them manually.

Comment: He's looking for a way without .last()

Comment: OP *tried* with .last but couldn't get it to work.  But it does explain your answer, thank you for clarifying.